# Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://server:9081/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube

SonarQube - 5.3
C# Plugin - 5.0
SonarQube Scanner 2.1
TFS 2015 Update 2.1

When I execute build on build server, it says

> Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://server:9081/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

I can login to Sonar server, I have also added path of Sonar `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` in path variable under environment variables.

Am I missing anything here?

Can anybody please help me to solve this?

```
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6290351Z Checking if artifacts directory exists: D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\a
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6290351Z Deleting artifacts directory.
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6330353Z Creating artifacts directory.
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6330353Z Checking if test results directory exists: D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\TestResults
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6330353Z Deleting test results directory.
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6340353Z Creating test results directory.
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6880384Z Starting: Get sources
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6930387Z Entering TfsGitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6930387Z localPath=D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6930387Z clean=False
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6930387Z sourceBranch=refs/heads/master
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6930387Z sourceVersion=8a38426975d589b8ba02ae545fa989588221143c
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6940388Z Syncing repository: PSA (Git)
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6940388Z repository url=http://server:8080/tfs/AjayTestCollection/_git/PSA
2016-07-18T12:20:40.6950388Z checkoutSubmodules=False
2016-07-18T12:20:40.7570424Z Starting fetch...
2016-07-18T12:20:40.9230519Z Checking out 8a38426975d589b8ba02ae545fa989588221143c to D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s
2016-07-18T12:20:40.9570538Z Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository PSA at commit 8a38426975d589b8ba02ae545fa989588221143c
2016-07-18T12:20:40.9570538Z commit=8a38426975d589b8ba02ae545fa989588221143c
2016-07-18T12:20:40.9570538Z Leaving TfsGitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-07-18T12:20:41.0360583Z Running tasks
2016-07-18T12:20:41.0510592Z Starting task: NuGet restore **\*.sln
2016-07-18T12:20:41.0770607Z Set workingFolder to default: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.17
2016-07-18T12:20:41.1000620Z Executing the powershell script: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.17\NuGetInstaller.ps1
2016-07-18T12:20:41.3220747Z D:\BuildAgent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s\CIBuildPSA\CIBuildPSA.sln"  -NonInteractive
2016-07-18T12:20:41.6210918Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
2016-07-18T12:20:41.6870956Z Finishing task: NuGetInstaller
2016-07-18T12:20:41.6950960Z Starting task: Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube
2016-07-18T12:20:41.6970961Z Executing the powershell script: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\SonarQubePreBuild.aps1
2016-07-18T12:20:41.8101026Z ##[debug]
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0451161Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0461161Z Default properties file was not found at D:\BuildAgent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0471162Z Pre-processing started.
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0481162Z Preparing working directories...
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0491163Z Checking for updates...
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0511164Z ##[error]Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://server:9081/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0521165Z ##[error]Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0531165Z ##[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0821182Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2016-07-18T12:20:42.0961190Z Finishing task: SonarQubePreBuild
2016-07-18T12:20:42.1451218Z Starting task: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
2016-07-18T12:20:42.1541223Z Set workingFolder to default: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3601341Z ##[debug]check path : D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3601341Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3611341Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3611341Z ##[debug]load strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3611341Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3621342Z ##[debug]Contents=**\bin\release\**
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3621342Z ##[debug]SourceFolder=D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3621342Z ##[debug]check path : D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3631342Z ##[debug]TargetFolder=D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\a
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3631342Z ##[debug]CleanTargetFolder=false
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3631342Z ##[debug]OverWrite=false
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3631342Z ##[debug]include content pattern: **\bin\release\**
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3881357Z ##[debug]find D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3891357Z ##[debug]179 matches.
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3951361Z ##[debug]allFiles contains 128 files
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3951361Z ##[debug]Include matching D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\s\**\bin\release\**
2016-07-18T12:20:42.3991363Z ##[debug]Include matched 0 files
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4001364Z ##[debug]load strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\lib.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4011364Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4021365Z found 0 files
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4081368Z Finishing task: CopyFiles
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4121370Z Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop
2016-07-18T12:20:42.4131371Z Set workingFolder to default: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28
2016-07-18T12:20:42.5991477Z ##[debug]check path : D:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6001478Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6001478Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6011479Z ##[debug]load strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\task.json
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6011479Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6021479Z ##[debug]system.hosttype=build
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6021479Z ##[debug]PathtoPublish=D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\a
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6021479Z ##[debug]check path : D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\a
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6031480Z ##[debug]ArtifactName=drop
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6031480Z ##[debug]ArtifactType=Container
2016-07-18T12:20:42.6041480Z ##[debug]TargetPath=\\my\share\Main_Sonar\20160718.7
2016-07-18T12:20:42.9871699Z Max Concurrent Uploads 4, Max Creators 1
2016-07-18T12:20:43.0141715Z Found 0 files to upload.
2016-07-18T12:20:43.0171717Z Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 0
2016-07-18T12:20:43.0181717Z Uploaded artifact 'D:\BuildAgent\_work\8\a' to container folder 'drop' of build 102.
2016-07-18T12:20:43.2781866Z Associated artifact 83 with build 102
2016-07-18T12:20:43.2871871Z Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts
2016-07-18T12:20:43.2891872Z ##[error]Task SonarQubePreBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
```

Comment: Where are you referencing the plugin?  Show that line.  It looks like you're trying to point to a URL, and that doesn't seem to make a lot of sense given what you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I have added log files details in original post, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing SonarQube server, you need to sign in the sever as an administrator, go to the Update Center (**Settings | System | Update Center**), and install the **SonarQube C# Plug-in**.

Also, SonarQube must be **restarted** after installing the plugin.

You may check whether you have completed the steps above. In the following link, there is detailed guide of how to install and configure SonarQube, you can chek it:

https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/installation-and-configuration.md#setup-sonarqube-server

Comment: In Update center, i can see C# plugin 5.0 is installed and latest one is 5.3.1

Do you see, if i am missing anything else here?

Comment: I again gone thru configuration
Apart from SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, i dont see any issue

I am not sure how build will pickup the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe as in configuration nothing is mentioned about it.

And it seems error is also misleading, as we do not have any such folder structure here.

Can you please throw more lights on the same?

Comment: OK, so i was reading and found that Start & end step is using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe only, so actually this is not the issue

Am i Right?

Comment: While creating service end point, i need to mention full URL i.e.
http://server:9000/sonar

Now its working fine, thanks for your help